# Add vertical line and figures on cover page

Tags: rules, center

I was reading this post [How to add a vertical line and figures on the titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211215/192122), and I need to do like this image (3 images: one on the left side of the vertical line, one on the right side and one at the bottom of the left side; `centering` the text; `lengthen` the vertical line all over the page).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=4cm}
\begin{titlepage}
    \hspace*{-2cm}%\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}

    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hspace{1cm}}l}
    \textcolor{black!70!black}{\rule[-0.9\textheight]{1pt}{0.9\textheight}} % Vertical line
     &
     \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.85\textwidth}}
      \\
     {\Huge\bfseries My title} \\[3cm]
     {\Large Some more text}\\[6cm]
     {\fbox{\begin{minipage}{15em}
The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
  dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
  dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog.
\end{minipage}}}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would do the whole page using a tikzpicture [overlay, remember picture] relative to (current page).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211218/24644